# IIS 7 Require SSL automatically redirect to https://

Tags: https, security-certificate, iis7

I've configured IIS 7 to require SSL. Can I automatically redirect non-SSL requests to be encrypted?

For example, if a user types in `http://domain.example`, can IIS redirect the request to `https://domain.example` rather than display the 403 error page?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

There are a few ways you can do this but if you have the [URL Rewrite Module](http://www.iis.net/download/urlrewrite) installed, it's fairly easy and a good way to do it.

You can paste the below configuration into your site's web.config file [(enclosed in the `<system.webServer></system.webServer>` section)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1738986/2404470)

```
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
<rewrite>  
  <rules> 
   <rule name="https redirect">      
      <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="false" />     
         <conditions>        
            <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="false" />      
         </conditions>      
      <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Found" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" />    
   </rule>  
  </rules>
</rewrite>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

**OR** you can use the IIS's UI to make a new rule like in the below screenshot.

[image: Screenshot of IIS rewrite rule for redirecting http traffic to https.]

Comment: What does the off signify? this answer works btw

Comment: Ah!  What you gave for the web.config was perfect.  I put that in my configs and everything went exactly how I wanted.  I know we aren't supposed to say thanks in comments, so I'm doing by saying that it works wonderfully!

Answer (score 1):

You could also use [UrlRewriter.NET](http://urlrewriter.net/). The rules to use with that, look like this:

```
<rewriter>
    <if header="HTTPS" match="^OFF$">
        <redirect url="(.*)" to="https://yourdomain.example$1"/>
    </if>
</rewriter>
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to disable 'Require SSL' in SSL Settings. Then you can follow Scott's solution.

RuslanY Blog's blog has a bunch of useful rules for IIS:
[10 URL Rewriting Tips and Tricks](https://ruslany.net/2009/04/10-url-rewriting-tips-and-tricks/)